# Wie drückt man auf Deutsch die Uhrzeit aus?

Tags: time

Wie nennt man auf Deutsch die Uhrzeit?

Ich kenne die Varianten

- viertel nach zwei
- zwei Uhr fünfzehn
- viertel drei

Gibt es eine offizielle "Zeitsprache"?

> How do you express the time of day in German?
>
> I know the variations,
>
> - viertel nach zwei (Quarter past two)
> - zwei Uhr fünfzehn (Two fifteen)
> - viertel drei      ("Quarter three")
>
> is there an official standard?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Die offizielle Verwendung unterscheidet sich in Deutsch von der gesprochenen.

**Offiziell:**

10.00: zehn Uhr
10.05: zehn Uhr fünf
10.10: zehn Uhr zehn
10.15: zehn Uhr fünfzehn
10.20: zehn Uhr zwanzig
10.25: zehn Uhr fünfundzwanzig
10.30: zehn Uhr dreißig
10.35: zehn Uhr fünfunddreißig
10.40: zehn Uhr vierzig
10.45: zehn Uhr fünfundvierzig
10.50: zehn Uhr fünfzig
10.55: zehn Uhr fünfundfünfzig
11.00: elf Uhr

14.00: vierzehn Uhr
14.05: vierzehn Uhr fünf
14.10: vierzehn Uhr zehn
14.15: vierzehn Uhr fünfzehn
14.20: vierzehn Uhr zwanzig
14.25: vierzehn Uhr fünfundzwanzig
14.30: vierzehn Uhr dreißig
14.35: vierzehn Uhr fünfunddreißig
14.40: vierzehn Uhr vierzig
14.45: vierzehn Uhr fünfundvierzig
14.50: vierzehn Uhr fünfzig
14.55: vierzehn Uhr fünfundfünfzig
15.00: fünfzehn Uhr

**Umgangssprache:**

9.00/21.00: neun
9.05/21.05: fünf nach neun
9.10/21.10: zehn nach neun
9.15/21.15: viertel nach neun
9.20/21.20: zwanzig nach neun / zehn vor halb zehn
9.25/21.25: fünf vor halb zehn
9.30/21.30: halb zehn
9.35/21.35: fünf nach halb zehn
9.40/21.40: zwanzig vor zehn / zehn nach halb zehn
9.45/21.45: viertel vor zehn
9.50/21.50: zehn vor zehn
9.55/21.55: fünf vor zehn
10.00/22.00: zehn

Während die Mitte zwischen zwei vollen Stunden einheitlich mit *halb* und der Angabe der folgenden Stunde bezeichnet wird (z.B. halb drei für 2 Uhr 30 Minuten), gibt es verschiedene **regionale Unterschiede** für die **Viertelstunden**.

Zum Beispiel 7.15 Uhr:

- *viertel nach sieben:* Rheinland, Westniederdeutschland und in Teilen Altbayerns
- *viertel ab sieben:* Schweiz
- *viertel über sieben:* Österreich (nicht ausschließlich)
- *viertel acht:* Ostniederdeutschland, Sachsen, Thüringen, Franken, Schwaben, Ostösterreich

7.45 Uhr:

- *viertel vor acht*: Westniederdeutschland, Rheinland, Schweiz
- *dreiviertel acht*: Ostniederdeutschland, Sachsen, Thüringen, Franken, Hessen, Pfalz Schwaben, Bayern, Österreich

In Grenzgebieten werden beide Formen verwendet. Beide Formen sind überregional durchaus verständlich.

Alle Varianten dieser Uhrzeitangaben mittels Viertelstunden sind ausschließlich im Zwölfstundensystem üblich. Es ist zum Beispiel falsch, *viertel nach dreizehn* zu sagen.

Comment: What a fine answer!

Comment: Ich vermute, bei 9:20 soll es "zehn vor halb zehn" heißen. BTW: Benutzt man Doppelpunkte um die Zeit zu trennen oder einfache Punkte?

Comment: @swegi klar, danke für den Hinweis! Man benutzt einfache Punkte in Deutsch.

Comment: Ich benutze fast immer Doppelpunkte zum trennen von Stunde und Minute - hast dazu, daß man einfache Punkte verwendet, eine Quelle an der Hand?

Comment: @mbx: Habe nachgeschlagen `:` und `.` können verwendet werden. Hab das noch anders gelernt. Danke! http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uhrzeit#Schreibweise

Comment: @splattne: du könntest noch die regionalen Unterschiede zur vollen Uhrzeit hinzufügen. In München hat man mich z.B. schief angeguckt als ich Sachen wie "Es ist fünf vor um" oder "wir treffen uns dann um" gesagt habe.

Comment: Oh, und noch ein Fun Fact: Gibt sogar Dörfer mit eigener Zeitangabe: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hormersdorf#Mundartuhr

Comment: "Zehn vor halb" kenne ich persönlich nicht, "Fünf vor halb" schon. Da scheint es wohl auch regionale Unterschiede zu geben.

Comment: "Dreiviertel irgendwas" ist zB im Rheinland unüblich und durchaus nicht verständlich. Da könntest Du genauso gut fünfzwölftel oder einen beliebigen anderen Bruch sagen. Punkte sind bei der Uhrzeit falsch per DIN 5008, siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uhrzeit#Schreibweise; es werden Doppelpunkte verwendet.

Comment: Benutzt mal Eindrittel Neun oder 40 vor 9 um Eure Umgebung zu testen. Für Fortgeschrittene: "7 Uhr 80".

Comment: @Robert Tja, der deutsche Sprachraum hört halt nicht unter dem Weißwurstäquator auf. Deswegen steht das mit den regionalen Unterschieden genau in meiner Antwort. Gelesen?Außerdem: Die DIN ist nicht der einzige Maßstab für Schreibweisen. Siehe: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/uhrzeitangaben

Answer (score 5):

Neben der präzisen Uhrzeitangabe in Stunden und Minuten, wie in *"Vierzehn Uhr Fünfzehn"* ist es üblich, die Stunde in Viertel aufzuteilen. Diese Vorgehensweise wird aber im Norden anders gehandhabt als im Süden und Osten.

Im Norden (und auch in anderen Regionen verständlich und richtig) bezeichnet man

- das Viertel **nach** einer Stunde: *"viertel nach zwei" = 14:15 Uhr
- das Viertel **vor** einer Stunde: *"viertel vor drei" = 14:45 Uhr
- die Hälfte **vor** einer Stunde: *"halb drei"* = 14:30 Uhr

Im Süden und Osten bezeichnet man die Uhrzeit wie folgt:

- das Viertel **bis zur nächsten** Stunde: *"viertel drei"* = 14:15 Uhr
- das Dreiviertel **zur nächsten** Stunde: *"dreiviertel drei*" = 14:45 Uhr
- die Hälfte bis **zur nächsten** Stunde: *"halb drei"* = 14:30 Uhr

Diese unterschiedlich gehandhabten Zeitangaben verwirrt durchaus auch die Muttersprachler. Deshalb wird bei Zeitangaben, die präzise sein müssen, gerne auf die Vierteleinteilung verzichtet.

Kinder haben im Süden einen Merkspruch, mit dem sie die Uhrzeitangaben lernen und üben können:

> "Viertel - Halber - Dreiviertel - Ganz: Ührlein, Ührlein dreh dein' Schwanz"

Dabei dreht da Kind schnell seinen rechten Zeigefinger auf der linken Handfläche und muss die Zeitangabe im Viertel sagen, an der der Finger am Ende des Spruchs stehen blieb.

Comment: Die Einteilung Nord/Süd kommt mir zu vereinfacht vor. Ich wohnte einst in Trier, wo man viertel vor sagt, aber sich nicht als Norddeutscher versteht.

Answer (score 4):

Normalerweise sagt man, dass "viertel nach zwei" in Westdeutschland und "viertel drei" in Ostdeutschland gesagt wird. Es ist allerdings höchsten ein gute Annährung an die tatsächliche regionale Weise Uhrzeiten zu sagen.

Offiziell würde man 2:15 Uhr oder 14:15 Uhr schreiben. Sagen kann man viel aber "zwei Uhr fünfzehn" ist soweit ich weiß überall üblich.

Comment: Bei Arzthelferinnen und Fremdenführen ja. Bei denen ärgere ich mich regelmäßig, das die keine klaren Termine im 24 Stunden System machen können oder wollen.

Comment: analog dazu: "dreiviertel" in Ostdt. und einigen Regionen in SüdDt.= "Viertel vor" im Westen

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt bei den Uhrzeiten noch ein zweites Problem. In Deutschland viele Leute das 12H System, aber ohne Angabe ob Vormittag oder Nachmittag.

Ich selbst sage zum Beispiel durchaus

> jetzt ist ungefähr halb 12.

Wenn ich auf eine Digitaluhr schaue lese ich die

> dreiundzwanzig Uhr siebenunddreißig
>   (23:37)

einfach ab. Wenn ich Termine abspreche verwende ich aber konsequent das 24 Stunden System.

**Edit:**

> Also wir treffen uns um vierzehn Uhr
>   fünfzehn.